# How does xorg paint stacked windows?

Tags: xorg, window-manager, window

I was reading a book called `Low Level X Window Programming` by Ross Maloney. He was talking about one of the key aspects of a stacked window system i.e restoration of "hidden" contents when you "remove" a window.

Normally you would expect the content "behind" to be immediately visible. However, apparently, this is not something that an `x` implementation has to provide though some does.

> The *save under* and *backing store* services differ slightly. In save
>   under, the contents of the screen onto which a window is mapped is
>   save by the server at the instance before the window is mapped, using
>   the memory of the server.

1. If this is not something that `x` server provides, should it be implemented in the client side?
2. How do some of the typical window manager implement stacking?
3. If `xorg` does provide this feature, is there any specific algorithm that can be used especially for "save under"? I didn't understand how saving a copy of the overlapping area can be used later especially when you have multiple overlaps =) My mind is already blowing! Can such delta's be used to reconstruct the stack?

If not, does it repaint each of the stacked window one by one in case of a random window removal? Wikipedia says the following:

> Stacking is a relatively slow process, requiring the redrawing of
>   every window one-by-one, from the rear-most and outer-most to the
>   front most and inner-most. Many stacking window managers don't always
>   redraw background windows. Others can detect when a redraw of all
>   windows is required, as some applications request stacking when their
>   output has changed. Re-stacking is usually done through a function
>   call to the window manager, which selectively redraws windows as
>   needed. For example, if a background window is brought to the front,
>   only that window should need to be redrawn.

PS: I know this is a big question, but it would be helpful to get some pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [backing store](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Backing_Store_Attribute) and [save under](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Save_Under_Flag) are attributes/flags that can be set when creating a window with `XCreateWindow()`. However, they're only hints to the X11 server, are not on by default, and are not really worth the trouble with modern hardware.

Generally, when (part of) a background window becomes visible, the X11 server will send an `Expose` event to the X11 client, which should cause it to redraw it. Since those are only hints, the X11 server may still send an `Expose` even if the client had set both `.backing_store = Always` on the window and `CWSaveUnder` on the popup windows it opened on top of it.

There are also interfaces which allows a client to query if the server implements backing store and save under: `XDoesBackingStore()` and `XDoesSaveUnders()`.

The window manager has nothing to do with all this; it does not redraw any windows (other than its own: the title bars, close buttons).

Comment: When you say "the X11 server will send an Expose event to the X11 client", does that mean client has to do something for that? Perhaps `map`? But wait that might map the whole window?

Comment: The client will have to either call `XSelectInput()` with `ExposureMask` or set it in the `event_mask` when creating the window. You should read the one page doc the links from my answer point to -- it contains just *everything* about X11 programming, except for the X11 extensions.

Comment: And of course, the window will have to be mapped in order to generate `Expose` events; however, it could be mapped and fully hidden, in which case no expose events will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

> If not, does it repaint each of the stacked window one by one in case of a random window removal?

Most popular desktops use the more recent XCOMPOSITE extension.  The entire window contents is rendered to off-screen buffers, so they are all available to the compositing manager without needing to request applications to redraw them.

Here is an excerpt from the [official site](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/CompositeExt/):

> This extension causes a entire sub-tree of the window hierarchy to be rendered to an off-screen buffer. Applications can then take the contents of that buffer and do whatever they like. The off-screen buffer can be automatically merged into the parent window or merged by external programs, called compositing managers. Compositing managers enable lots of fun effects.

Comment: Nothing to do with it. And yes, Xorg does implement backing-store, though it's not enabled by default (with modern hardware, it's not really worth it; but the backing store implementation was the reason for some nasty legal stuff, Rob Pike heckling, etc) The XCOMPOSITE extension is basically about something different: implementing translucent, alpha-compositing windows.

Comment: Thanks @sourcejedi. Do you know of any algorithms that can be used to implement "save under" kind of thing?!

Comment: @UncleBilly, interesting. I am just reading this https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2006/06/i-cant-find-this-on-web-so-here.html from Rob Pikes' blog.

Comment: @UncleBilly and Nishant: edited. XCOMPOSITE is related in the sense that using it removes the need for any other solution to this problem.